# How to search exact or closest word in array, using javaScript RegEx?

Tags: javascript, string

In my app I have implemented local search using Regular expressions, I have problem, I could not find solution even after much searching, as you can see I have `words` array, Which I filter based on condition, I want to implement something like that:

> if user writes  `ele` into the search box, I want to get `['electric', 'elektric']`, same should happen if user writes `ric` into the input field result: `['electric', 'elektric']`, but In case the user enters the exact name, for example `electric` result should be : `['electric']`
> At last, if input will be  `cooling` result should be `['engine cooling']`

As you can see, My goal is to  system search exact word or exact letters or the closest logical option. I will take any advice, thanx

```js
let words = ['electric', 'elektric', 'engine cooling']

function bestMatch(event){
 let match = words.filter((e) => new  RegExp(`^${event.value}`,"ig").test(e));
 console.log(match)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="best match" onchange="bestMatch(this)" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.*` before and after to get the regex to work so that position in word doesn't matter, though regex is unneccesary based on your requirements. Instead you can use `includes`. Finally `onkeyup` might be better/faster in getting results

With regex:

```js
let words = ['electric', 'elektric', 'engine cooling']

function bestMatch(event){
 let match = words.filter((e) => new  RegExp(`^.*${event.value}.*`,"ig").test(e));
 console.log(match)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="best match" onchange="bestMatch(this)" />
```

Without regex (and using `onkeyup`):

```js
let words = ['electric', 'elektric', 'engine cooling']

function bestMatch(event){
 let match = words.filter((e) => e.includes(event.value.toLowerCase()))
 console.log(match)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="best match" onkeyup="bestMatch(this)" />
```

Comment: thanks for solution, but what if I want to show both `[elektric, electric]` result if input value will be   `elektric` (because `ele` and `tric` is matched in both word)? how i can handle this?

Comment: @Ernest_lover you can test both cases (search `ele` or `ric`) and get the expected result, click run code snippet

Comment: One more thing you can do is `e.includes(event.value.toLowerCase()) || event.value.includes(e.toLowerCase())` to also adjust for additional unrequired characters. For example, "electriccc" will still return ['electric']